# Condition variable waits indefinitely even if condition is met

Tags: c++, multithreading, condition-variable

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

std::mutex  mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;

int main() {
  int balance = 0;
  std::thread withdraw([&](int amt){
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(mtx);
      cv.wait(ul, [balance, amt]{ return balance >= amt; });
      balance  -= amt;
      std::cout << "Amount deducted: " << amt << ", current balance: " << balance << endl;
  }, 500);

  std::thread deposit([&](int amt){
      std::lock_guard<mutex> lg(mtx);
      balance += amt;
      std::cout << "Amount added: " << amt << ", current balance: " << balance << endl;
      cv.notify_one();
  }, 1000);

  withdraw.join();
  deposit.join();
  return 0;
}
```

In this piece of code, there's a `withdraw` thread waiting on a condition variable with a predicate on the balance is greater than or equal to the withdrawal amount. There's another producer thread called `deposit` that increments the balance and wakes up the `withdraw` thread to test on the predicate. However, the `withdraw` thread is blocking indefinitely. I expect to see `Amount deducted: 500, current balance: 500`. But it never comes through.

```
➜  synchronization git:(master) ✗ ./a.out
Amount added: 1000, current balance: 1000
```

I am not sure about whether the `[balance, amt]{ return balance >= amt; }` is correct. How do I get it work? Thanks

Comment: You capture `balance` and `atm` by copy, they'll never change. You ought to capture the one modified by reference: `[&balance, amt]`

Comment: @ALX23z Thanks for the response. Your suggestion works. I don't get the point why balance needs to be passed by reference in the capture of the predicate. It is readonly and the change made by the `deposit` thread should be visible in the `withdrawal` thread regardless of how it gets passed, right?

Comment: A change to `balance` made in `deposit` is visible in `withdrawal`. But that's not what the lambda predicate compares to `amt`. Instead, it compares a copy of `balance` that it captured when the lambda was first created. That copy never changes, even while `balance` does. Your `wait` call is equivalent to `cv.wait(ul, [balance_copy = balance, amt]{ return balance_copy >= amt; });` - in this formulation, it should be clear what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Change your line

`cv.wait(ul, [balance, amt]{ return balance >= amt; });`

to

`cv.wait(ul, [&]{ return balance >= amt; });`.

Here `std::thread withdraw([&](int amt)` you did that, why not to keep?.

If you need more examples, have a look here: [lambda-expression](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/lambda-expression).